# CI/CD populate static html file?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

new to ci/cd I am tasked to create a simple pipeline that would render a static index.html file.
This file would be populated with a value  from an environment variable.(say the commit_sha ).
I dont quite get how to have a variable in a static file.
Can a build step in a ci/cd pipeline render html content in a simple way ?
TY

Comment: ok so I started adding some script place holder in the index.html so the pipeline should be able to inject those variables 

```<script> 
  var myVar= {{myVar}};  
</script> 
<html>  
echo this is {{myVar}}  
</html>  
```
But I still dont see how a build step would generate a new file and replace the existing one .
Ideas ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.